# turn the main form in the secondary

Tags: vb.net, forms

I wrote a code using the main form but now I realized that the entire form (and its code) should be called from the main form.

Is there a way to add a new form (which will be the main one) and turn the main form in the secondary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I have undestood you correctly, what you need is this: in Visual Studio, you must go to: (in the menu options) PROJECT->PROPERTIES->APPLICATION (names can change, I have the spanish version) and there is a combo where you can select the main form.

Hope this can help you. Bye!